# Canon eos rebel sl3 lens adapter

Tags: canon, adapter, vintage

I am very new to photography so forgive me if I don’t use correct terminology. I just got a Canon EOS Rebel SL3. 
A friend of mine gifted me some vintage lenses. But I can’t figure out which adapter I need to purchase to use the vintage lenses on my new Canon. I don’t know even where to start as I don’t know the different lenses that well or how this works.

I have the following lenses:

1. Promaster SP MC Zoom 1:4.5 f=80-200mm
2. Soligor MC zoom+macro 28-70mm 1:3.5-4.5
3. SMC Pentax-M 1:2 50mm

Any information would be so helpful as this is all new to me and I am so lost.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all three lenses were for the same “vintage” camera, you will need a [Pentax K mount to Canon EF-S mount adapter.](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1349589-REG/vello_la_cef_pk_pentax_k_lens_mount.html)

These lenses will be manual focus and manual aperture only. They might be difficult to use for a beginner, and the optical quality is probably not as good as your kit lens.

[image]